# How to display each component in an array with an ngfor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, components, ngfor

I'm setting up a page to hold a bunch of data input from the user, a component `user-info`, contains an array of n other components called `semester-info`.

I have an `ngfor` loop going through an array of `Components` and attempting to display all of them. Instead its just displaying the text, `Object object`. I have the component working and if i instead do

`<app-empty-term  id = "1" semsester={{semesterCount}} startYear={{currentUserYear}} term ={{currentUserTerm}} class="card">`

It displays as expected, so i know the component is working as expected.

I already made sure that elements are being added to my terms array and that is correct, and if i do something like

`{{element.name}}`

I get the expected answer for each component in the array.

I've done a bunch of research and haven't had too much luck which is making me start to wonder if this is possible or if i should approach this in a different way

```
<div id="sampleContainer" class="card-container" *ngFor="let element of terms">
        <div>{{element}}</div>
    <!-- <app-empty-term  id = "1" semsester={{semesterCount}} startYear= {{currentUserYear}} term ={{currentUserTerm}} class="card"></app- empty-term> -->
    </div>
```

> The commented out portion of this code is a somewhat sample of what I
>   expected, In this case if that is uncommented there will be n
>   app-empty-term components for a terms array of size n, however they
>   are not linked to my term array so if i try to access their data, the
>   expected data will not be there

Im expected the component to be displayed n times, however its just displaying the text Object object n times.

Answer (score 0):

if your `element` in each iteration is `component`, then this should work as expected, you can learn more about `*ngComponentOutlet` here [ngComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet)

```
<div id="sampleContainer" class="card-container" *ngFor="let element of terms">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="element"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Im getting the error:  ERROR Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?                         Also I did add it to my app.module.ts file under entry components

Comment: @JakeSchichko is your `element` component type ?, if so can you show an example where you added your component as entry components.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you'd have an `@Input` property on your `EmptyTermComponent`. Something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-empty-term',
  templateUrl: './empty-term.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./empty-term.component.css']
})
export class EmptyTermComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() term: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And then you'd pass the `term` as an Input in your Parent Component:

Something like this:

```
<div id="sampleContainer" class="card-container" *ngFor="let term of terms">
    <!-- <div>{{element}}</div> -->
    <app-empty-term
    [term]=term
    class="card">
  </app-empty-term>
</div>
```

Assuming that you have the `terms` array that looks something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  terms = [
    { id: 1, semesterCount: 1, startYear: 2021, term: 1, name: 'Term 1' },
    { id: 2, semesterCount: 2, startYear: 2022, term: 2, name: 'Term 2' },
    { id: 3, semesterCount: 3, startYear: 2023, term: 3, name: 'Term 3' },
    { id: 4, semesterCount: 4, startYear: 2024, term: 4, name: 'Term 4' },
  ];
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p1yxkv?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: This is similar to my original solution. The problem, or at least what i think a problem would be for this is that if element is edited, you would not be able to access it using the terms array

Comment: The problem that you're mentioning is a totally different issue that you didn't quite mention in the original post. BTW, whenever the element is edited and saved. you would have to update the original data too. It would make more sense to have a single source of truth in this case. You might have to create a REST API that stores the updates to this data for you. And then you'd have to create a service that interacts with that service and receives the updated data every time there's an AJAX request made to it. Did that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it did, I think i over complicated the code, it could most likely be done in one component instead of 2 to prevent from having to do any of this

Comment: Making a separate component would be a better design though.